# Phone Validation regular expression with exception for TEXT and TEXTTWO

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validation-engine

I'm currently using the jQuery validation Engine with jQuery 1.10. After peeking into the validation script itself (which, for phone numbers is a custom type), I noticed that it utilizes the following regex:

```
/^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/
```

What I'm trying to do is also allow "TEXT" and "TEXTTWO" as acceptable values. I've tried:

```
/^?(TEXT|TEXTTWO)^?([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/
```

...and several variations on the theme without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good for you for attempting! But it seems there's just one thing you're misunderstanding: `^` is an *anchor*—it matches the beginning of a string—it cannot be quantified, *e.g.* made optional via `?`, nor does it make sense to appear *after* some part of the string has already been matched, since then it could definitely not be the beginning of the string. Try this instead:

```
/^TEXT|TEXTTWO|([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/
```

So, you had the right idea with alternation (`|`). Note that alternation has one of the lowest precedence of all operators in regex, so no grouping is necessary here.

Comment: Wow, I KNEW I was close with the | selector! This makes sense (in hindsight), and I feel like I understand regexp more. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
/^(TEXT|TEXTTWO|([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?)$/
```